# Best way to manage thread pool against database queue

Tags: c#, .net, database, winforms, multithreading

I have a data table full of summary entries and my software needs to go through and reach out to a web service to get details, then record those details back to the database. Looping through the table synchronously while calling the web service and waiting for the response is too slow (there are thousands of entries) so I'd like to take the results (10 or so at a time) and thread it out so it performs 10 operations at the same time.

My experience with C# threads is limited to say the least, so what's the best approach? Does .NET have some sort of threadsafe queue system that I can use to make sure that the results get handled properly and in order?

Comment: What version of .Net are you using? There are big improvements in multithreaded programming in .Net 4.

Comment: Should have included that.. Currently targeting 3.5 but I can go 4.0 without much trouble.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on which version of the .NET Framework you have two pretty good options.

You can use `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` in any version.

```
int pending = table.Rows.Count;
var finished = new ManualResetEvent(false);
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
  DataRow capture = row; // Required to close over the loop variable correctly.
  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
    (state) =>
    {
      try
      {
        ProcessDataRow(capture);
      }
      finally
      {
         if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref pending) == 0) 
         {
           finished.Set();  // Signal completion of all work items.
         }
      }
    }, null);
}
finished.WaitOne(); // Wait for all work items to complete.
```

If you are using .NET Framework 4.0 you can use the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx).

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
  DataRow capture = row; // Required to close over the loop variable correctly.
  tasks.Add(
    Task.Factory.StartNew(
      () =>
      {
        ProcessDataRow(capture);        
      }));
}
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray()); // Wait for all work items to complete.
```

There are many other reasonable ways to do this. I highlight the patterns above because they are easy and work well. In the absence of specific details I cannot say for certain that either will be a perfect match for your situation, but they should be a good starting point.

**Update:**

I had a short period of subpar cerebral activity. If you have the TPL available you could also use `Parallel.ForEach` as a simpler method than all of that `Task` hocus-pocus I mentioned above.

```
Parallel.ForEach(table.Rows,
  (DataRow row) =>
  {
    ProcessDataRow(row);
  });
```

Comment: By the way, you can actually use the TPL in 3.5 if you download the Reactive Extensions backport from the Microsoft website.

Comment: Awesome stuff -- many thanks to everyone. Looks like there are several ways to skin this cat!

Comment: Just one thing (and I know, I'll go RTFM!), but how does this scale? I'll be doing thousands of these rows and I definitely don't want to start thousands of threads concurrently. I'm assuming (hoping?) there is some sort of limit built in so this doesn't bring the user's computer to a halt.

Comment: @MitchellV: `Thread.QueueUserWorkItem` and `Parallel.ForEach` will scale very well. `Task.StartNew` normally scales very well except that `Task.WaitAll` *may* have a 64 count limit if it uses `WaitHandle.WaitAll` behind the scenes, but I don't think it does. All of these methods use thread pooling techniques at their core so initiating thousands of work items should not be a problem.

Answer (score 5):

> Does .NET have some sort of threadsafe queue system that I can use to make sure that the results get handled properly and in order?

This was something added in .NET 4.  The [`BlockingCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) class, by defaults, acts as a thread safe queue for producer/consumer scenarios.

It makes it fairly easy to create a number of elements that "consume" from the collection and process, with one or more elements adding to the collection.

Comment: Very nice, I'll definitely check it out. Thanks!

Comment: What about the Concurrent Queue? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx?

Comment: @Dykam `BlockingCollection<T>`, by default, wraps a `ConcurrentQueue<T>`.  While you can use the CQ directly, if you want to work in a producer/consumer scenario, as described, BC makes this quite a bit simpler.